# How to get checkbox value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Can you please help me on this, I get the check box control value as false always even when I check the control in gridview.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");

    if (CheckBox1 != null)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            query = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label1") + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you databinding on Page_Load method? If yes, you must do this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = YourData;
}
```

If you don't do this, your `DataGridView` will be databound even if it is a `PostBack`. This way no matter what you checked, the `DataGridView` will be repopulated from the data source for your postbacks.

Using the above code, when you do `if(!IsPostBack)`, it will retain the checkbox's viewstate value and you get the correct `Checked` status.

Comment: Leniel can u please again help me, Is it right way to find the column value (label field) (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label1")

Comment: I think you must do this: `Label myLabel = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label1") as Label`; Then `var quey = myLabel.Text + ",";`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the checkbox design add the following attribute

> ToolTip="<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %> " and then following is the code behind

```
for (int i = 0; i < gdview.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string labeldetail = "";

        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)gdview.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");

        if (cbox != null)
        {
            if (cbox.Checked == true)
            {

                int rowsNo = (Convert.ToInt16(city.ToolTip) - 1); //Convert.ToInt16(SrNo);
               labeldetail = ((Label)gdview.Rows[rowsNo].FindControl("labelid")).Value;
```

}